# UIStringDrawing Change font color - cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

UIFont doesn't appear to manage color, is there a way to change the font color using UIStringDrawing.h or specifically:

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `UIColor`.  Specifically:

```
- (void) setFill;
```

For example:

```
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
[myString drawInRect:rect withFont:font];
```

Other methods include `setStroke` and just `set` to set both fill and stroke.  Fonts use the fill color.